# Necesito saber cómo insertar en MySQL los objetos que tengo almacenados en un ArrayList en Java sin PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

Tengo un ArrayList con Objetos y necesito insertar cada Objeto de dicho ArrayList en una tabla de MySQL. Los atributos de la clase del Objeto y la tabla de MySQL concuerdan perfectamente. El problema es que no sé cómo hacer la inserción de todos los Objetos en la tabla.

Comment: Hazlo con un for , por cada objeto en tu arrayList, agrega tu código para una mejor ayuda

Comment: Ya lo he conseguido. Era bastante fácil la verdad. Con un for ciertamente y accediendo a los getter de la clase. Estoy muy cansado y parecía más fácil preguntar que pensar XD. Muchas gracias @Charls de todas formas por tu tiempo.

Comment: ¿Por qué sin `PreparedStatement` cuando debería ser todo lo contrario?

Comment: Se trata de una prueba de clase, por lo que no era necesario PreparedStatement.
Estoy intentando enseñaros mi insertar mi código para que veas el resultado y poder ayudar a alguien que lo necesite pero no soy capaz. Ni con <code></code> ni con ``.

Answer (score 0):

Dejo aquí el código por si a alguien le sirve de ayuda.

```
public static void volcarArrayMov(ArrayList<Movimiento> ar, Connection conn) {
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        for(int i=0;i<ar.size();i++) {
            String sqlStr = "INSERT INTO movimientos VALUES(null, '" + ar.get(i).getFecha() + "',"+ "'" + ar.get(i).getCuentaOrigen() + "',"+ "'" + ar.get(i).getCuentaDestino() + "',"+ "'" +ar.get(i).getCantidad()+ "')";

            stmt.executeUpdate(sqlStr);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```